# I need hikvision camera which has ip 20.0.0.14 and user name/password is admin/12345 to run by python code

Tags: python

I need hikvision camera which has ip 20.0.0.14 and user name/password is admin/12345 to run by python code

the original camera code is

```
import cv2.cv as cv
import time

cv.NamedWindow("camera", 1)

capture = cv.CaptureFromCAM(0)

while True:
    img = cv.QueryFrame(capture)
    cv.ShowImage("camera", img)
    if cv.WaitKey(10) == 27:
        break
cv.DestroyAllWindows()
```

i need help please

Comment: I edited your post so that the code is properly showing in a code block, and thus the format does not get messed up. When you post a question or response, there is a button in the text editing toolbar, that if you select a block of text and click this button, it will be marked as code. Please use it in future posts.

Comment: I noticed that you've posted four or so questions to stack overflow, but you've not accepted the answer for any of them. When a response provides a sufficient answer, please use the green check mark to mark that answer as accepted. If no responses answer the question, then please comment as to how the answer is deficient.

Answer (score 3):

Here's the solution when using OpenCV3. In your sample code, you are not only not using the OpenCV2 interface, but you are accessing the very old cv (prior to OpenCV 2) interface. So my first suggestion is to get a current install of OpenCV working.

Possible source of rtsp urls for use with hikvision cameras:
https://www.ispyconnect.com/man.aspx?n=Hikvision

```
import cv2
# Note the following is the typical rtsp url for streaming from an ip cam
# source = "rtsp://user:password@ipaddress:port/<camera specific stuff>"
# Each manufacturer is different. For my alibi cameras, this would be
# a valid url to use with the info you provided.
source = "rtsp://admin:12345@20.0.0.14//Streaming/Channels/2"
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(source)

ok_flag = True
while ok_flag:
    (ok_flag, img) = cap.read()
    if not ok_flag: break
    cv2.imshow("some window", img)
    if cv2.waitKey(10) == 27:
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Also note that this code works the same if the source is the path to a valid video file (like an .avi), or for a web camera (in which case you pass the integer number of the webcam, like 0).

Another error in your post is the cv.CaptureFromCAM(0), which would be capturing from the first webcam installed on the computer, not an ip stream.